# How to call a search method in a _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

I'm trying to create a search method, that is called in my _Layout.cshtml and when I click on submit button, the user is redirected to "search view".

I' following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search), but the author call your method at index view and I need to call the method at _Layout to be redirect to another view that will give me the return of method.

This is my _Layout, is basic a nav-bar from bootstrap with a textfield and a button, that the user can put what he need to find:

```
    @model IEnumerable<TestTcc2.Models.Musica>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "IndexOuvinte", "Home")</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "IndexOuvinte", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Account", "Manage", "Account")</li>
                        <li>@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                            {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="container">

        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        @RenderBody()

    </div>
    <!--Fim container -->
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the method that I want to call at _Layout.cshtml:

```
public ActionResult Search(string search)
        {
            var musicas = from m in db.Musicas select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                musicas = musicas.Where(s => s.Nome.Contains(search));
                return RedirectToAction("Search"); //name of view that will return the data
            }
            return View(musicas);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you might consider specifying an `action` to the form or just use the appropriate helper to generate it:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "SomeController", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
```